# Which version to use when trying out Railscasts source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railscasts

I'm trying to get a railscasts working but apparently things have changed a lot in the last year... So how can you now against which version of ruby the railscast was done? The gemfile contains all versions of gems, but not the version of ruby to use. And no, it isn't all that backward compatible...

Comment: At the very least we probably need the particular Railscast you're referencing. In all likelyhood either 1.8.7 or 1.9.3 would work fine.

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby v1.9.2 was used for the ASCIIcast. In all likelihood Ryan Bates also used a Ruby v1.9.x for his Railscast.

```
/Users/eifion/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
```

Can be seen in the ASCIIcast at http://railscasts.com/episodes/257-request-specs-and-capybara?view=asciicast in any of the terminal outputs.

Nothing in the Rails cast indicates that it would not also work with 1.8.7 to me.

Answer (score 1):

Rails 3.0+ works best with ruby 1.9. So, it's better to use 1.9.3.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier to tell by looking at the coding used in the rails cast. If it tells you about asset pipeline then its Rails 3.1+. If it does not use pipeline but calls rails s then its 3.0. If it uses script/server then its 2.*.* version

Comment: The gemfile points to the rails version, but I'm talking about the ruby version...